# XCode 5 assets catalog with iPhone only application on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I've got an iPhone only application, and I'm using XCode 5 assets catalog.
What should I do to make sure that all the necessary icons are available also when installing to an iPad?

Is it enough to have the default set, or should I check the iPad assets from the right toolbar and add those?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it with just the iPhone assets and it is ok on iPad too. From what I can see a lower resolution icon than the one that would be needed it's being used, so it is a bit grainy, but the important thing to me is that the app icon isn't missing.